# Check whether $f_1$ and $f_2$ are measurable or not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Let , $P$ be a non-measurable subset of $E=(0,1)$. Define two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ on $E$ by $\displaystyle f_1(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} &\text{ if } x\in P\\0 &\text{ if } x\not \in P\end{cases}$    & $\displaystyle f_2(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\text{ if } x \in P\\\frac{1}{x} &\text{ if } x \not \in P\end{cases}$
>
> Test which one is measurable.

**My Work:**
We have , $E(|f_1|>0)=P$. As $P$ is non-measurable so $|f_1|$ is non-measurable & hence $f_1$ is non-measurable.

Again , $E(f_2=0)=P$. As $P$ is non-measurable so $f_2$ is non-measurable.

Is my solution correct ?  If wrong then detect my fallacy and correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks correct for $f_1$.

For $f_2$, it may be clearer to note that $\{f_2>0\}=(0,1)\setminus P$, the complement of $P$. Suppose to the contrary, $f_2$ is measurable, then $(0,1)\setminus P$ is measurable.

Then, $P=(0,1)\setminus ((0,1)\setminus P)$ is measurable since the collection of measurable sets is a sigma algebra. This is a contradiction.